# Is there a way to detect if there is an uncommitted transaction in H2?

Tags: transaction, jdbc, h2, auto-commit

I am using an H2 database with JDBC to create a connection with setAutoCommit(false).

I am currently programatically checking whether or not there is an uncommitted transaction, but I was wondering if there was a way to directly query H2 for information about this state.

I have found some information for other databases on this topic, but nothing so far on H2.

Comment: I asked the [same thing on StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31754214/642706). Surprisingly, there seems to be no way to do this in standard JDBC. Someone gave me a tip about a Postgres-specific way to query the status (IDLE, OPEN, FAILED)  of any existing transaction. I posted example code there that may be of interest, but you’ll need to find an H2-specific class to substitute for my Postgres-specific class.